# Get the math symbols from textbox and insert into database asp.net c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I am having textbox in a form. Users filling the form along with mathematical symbols but it is converting to some other character while storing to database(SQL). It should store the symbols, Can you tell me how do fix this issue?

Comment: Perhaps if you show your actual code we could be able to help. Remember, asking _why this code is not working_ and not showing the code is a reason to close a question

Comment: It sounds to me the problem is related to character sets. I recommend to read about that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am trying to insert "√25 = 5" but it is storing in table "v25 = 5".

Comment: Can you isolate the problem and then post the code of that. Without your code it is very difficult to answer your question.

Comment: thanks. Here i am trying,
insert into table(question) values('√25 = 5'). This is inserting that value

Answer (score 1):

Question column in your table should be able to store unicode characters, try change the type to nvarchar

```
create table test (
question nvarchar(10)
)

insert into test(question) values(N'√25 = 5')
```

Comment: Just want to add that since the source string is user-entered, the actual insert statement should be parameterized with a parameter type of SqlDbType.NVarChar and a length of 10.  The Unicode literal works for an illustration, though.

Answer (score 0):

The way your symbols are stored depend on the encoding of the SQL database. You need to select an encoding which can handle math symbols like Unicode (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode)